# Не могу понять, что не так

Tags: python, ооп, tkinter

Всегда вылазит else, помогите решить, что не так, я уже все пытался

```py
from tkinter import *
from math import *

class Programma:
    def __init__(self, main):
        def click():
            if(self.entry2 == "женский") and (self.entry2 == "Женский"):
                get = self.entry1.get()
                q = (int(get))
                res = (q - 110) * 1.15
                w = (str(res))
                self.label3["text"] = "Ответ " + (w)
            elif(self.entry2 == "мужской") and (self.entry2 == "Мужской"):
                get = self.entry1.get()
                q = (int(get))
                res = (q - 100) * 1.15
                w = (str(res))
                self.label3["text"] = "Ответ " + (w)
            else:
                self.label3["text"] = "Введите корректное значение!"

        self.label1 = Label(main, text = "Введите ваш рост (в сантиметрах):")
        self.entry1 = Entry(main)
        self.label2 = Label(main, text = "Введите ваш пол:")
        self.entry2 = Entry(main)
        self.btn1 = Button(main, text = "Проверить", command = click)
        self.label3 = Label(main, text = "Ответ")

        self.label1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.entry1.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        self.label2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.entry2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.btn1.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        self.label3.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

root = Tk()
root.title("Программа для расчета идеального веса")

p = Programma(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
if(self.entry2 == "женский") and (self.entry2 == "Женский"):
```

```py
elif(self.entry2 == "мужской") and (self.entry2 == "Мужской"):
```

Эти условия не выполняются никогда.
Не может одно и то же выражение одновременно равняться и `мужской`, и `Мужской`.
Если замените `and` на `or`, будет работать.

Но для таких случаев лучше использовать такую конструкцию:

```
if self.entry2.upper() == "ЖЕНСКИЙ"
```

В таком случае учитываются все регистры.

## UPD

Почитал документацию TKinter, для получения текста из поля нужно использовать метод `get()`:

```py
if self.entry2.get().upper() == "ЖЕНСКИЙ"
```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает

Comment: @darmsh попробуйте вывести `self.entry2` в консоль. Возможно, тип данных - не строка, тогда при сравнении нужно сравнивать не `self.entry2` с выражением, а `str(self.entry2)`. А конструкция с `upper()` будет выглядеть так: `str(self.entry2).upper()`. А ещё лучше - выведите в консоль не `self.entry2`, а `type(self.entry2)`. Должно вывестись `<class 'str'>`

Comment: Пишу str(self.entry2) все так же

Comment: @darmsh Обновил ответ, читайте `UPD`

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!